# Should there be a comma after "if X"?

Tags: punctuation, commas, conditionals

Consider the sentences:

> 1. If you agree with that, could you suggest us some references?
> 2. If you agree with that could you suggest us some references?

Which one is written correctly? Notice the use of "," in (1).

Comment: Proof reading is off topic. that said, I prefer the comma

Answer (score 3):

Not only is the comma fine, it is actually useful. Without it, the reader might parse the *that* not as a demonstrative pronoun, but as an adjectival *that*, expecting a noun to follow and getting caught off guard by a *could*. You'd be putting an unnecessary hurdle in his way.